# Why is Quinone used, while oxidising primary alcohols by Oppenauer Oxidation, instead of Acetone?

Tags: organic-chemistry, alcohols, organic-oxidation

Usually, during Oppenauer Oxidation, while oxidising secondary alcohols, acetone solution is used with Aluminium Tertiary Butoxide.
This results into the oxidation of secondary alcohol into a ketone, along with isopropanol as a side product.

I was told that if primary alcohol needs to be oxidised into an aldehyde, quinone is used instead of acetone. I fail to understand why is that the case, and how that would affect the mechanism of the reaction.

Comment: Do you have specific reference for your claim?

Comment: Some authentification is needed here. What is the solvent? Certainly not quinone! If an aldehyde were produced, in many instances condensation reactions would occur in the presence of strong base, presuming that it is required.

Answer (score 2):

OP has mentioned in the post that:

> I was told that if primary alcohol needs to be oxidized into an aldehyde, quinone is used instead of acetone. I fail to understand why is that the case, and how that would affect the mechanism of the reaction (Oppenauer Oxidation).

I have asked OP if there specific reference for his/her claim, but didn't get a response back. Yet, I have search for the answer and found there wasn't any proof for the claim. However, I think my following answer would satisfy some clearance for OP's curiosity.

Essentially, Oppenauer Oxidation is the reverse reaction of Meerwein−Schmidt−Ponndorf−Verley (MSPV) reduction. According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meerwein%E2%80%93Ponndorf%E2%80%93Verley_reduction),

> MSPV reduction in organic chemistry is the reduction of **ketones and aldehydes** to their corresponding alcohols utilizing aluminum alkoxide catalysis in the presence of a sacrificial alcohol. The advantages of the MPV reduction lie in its high chemoselectivity, and its use of a cheap environmentally friendly metal catalyst.

[image: MVP Reduction & Oppenauer Oxidation]

> The MSPV reduction was independently discovered by Albert Verley and the team of Hans Meerwein and Rudolf Schmidt in 1925. They found that a mixture of aluminium ethoxide and ethanol could reduce aldehydes to their alcohols. Ponndorf applied the reaction to ketones and upgraded the catalyst to aluminum isopropoxide in isopropanol (Ref.1-3).

The use of aluminum isopropoxide in isopropanol has led to the use of acetone in the reverse reaction, Oppenauer Oxidation introduced in 1937 (Ref.4).

Based on these facts, either ketone and aldehyde can be reduced or their corresponding alcohols can be oxidized either direction using best sacrificing ketone (acetone) or alcohol (isopropanol). Thus, need for quinone to prepare aldehyde is unheard of. For example, Ref. 5 shows a successful reduction of crotonaldehyde and cinnamaldehyde using isopropoxide, so why not the reversed reaction using acetone?

---

**References:**

1. Hans Meerwein and Rudolf Schmidt, "Ein neues Verfahren zur Reduktion von Aldehyden und Ketonen," *Justus Liebigs Annalen der Chemie* **1925**, *444(1)*, 221-238 (ODI: https://doi.org/10.1002/jlac.19254440112).
2. M. Verley, *Bull. Soc. Chim. Fr.* **1925**, *37*, 871−874.
3. Wolfgang Ponndorf, "Der reversible Austausch der Oxydationsstufen zwischen Aldehyden oder Ketonen einerseits und primären oder sekundären Alkoholen anderseits," *Angewandte Chemie* **1926**, *39(5)*, 138-143 (ODI: https://doi.org/10.1002/ange.19260390504).
4. R. V. Oppenauer, "Eine Methode der Dehydrierung von Sekundären Alkoholen zu Ketonen. I. Zur Herstellung von Sterinketonen und Sexualhormonen," *Recueil des Travaux Chimiques des Pays-Bas* **1937**, *56(2)*, 137-144 (ODI: https://doi.org/10.1002/recl.19370560206).
5. William G. Young, Walter H. Hartung, and Frank S. Crossley, "Reduction of Aldehydes with Aluminum Isopropoxide," *J. Am. Chem. Soc.* **1936**, *58(1)*, 100–102 (ODI: https://doi.org/10.1021/ja01292a033).